# XML Config data in a single line

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to display config file data in a single line.

Config file:

```xml
<Configuration>
  <Scripts>
   xyz100
   xyz101
   xyz102
  </Scripts>
</Configuration>
```

When I read this file data displays into number lines same like how it exists in config file:

```
xyz100
xyz101
xyz102
```

but I want to display in a single line:

```
xyz100   xyz101   xyz102
```

Comment: For help with your code: show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not that hard:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<Configuration>
  <Scripts>
   xyz100
   xyz101
   xyz102
  </Scripts>
</Configuration>
'@
$xml.Configuration.Scripts -replace "`n", ' '
```

Outputs:

```
xyz100    xyz101    xyz102
```